# Correct Colorbar Text Spacing in Matplotlib

Tags: python, unix, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to insert text in between ticks in my x-axis colorbar.

Using the below code, I'm able to produce this plot but, it appears that the math I'm doing`(1.8 * j + 1) / 12.0`isn't correctly proportioning the text to be centered between the ticks.

Code:

```
cbar = m.colorbar(ticks=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6], format='%0.f', location='bottom',pad="5%")

cbar.ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
for j, lab in enumerate(['No Precip','>0.01"','>0.10"','>0.25"','>0.50"','>1.00"','>2.00+"']):
cbar.ax.text((1.8 * j + 1) / 12.0, .5, lab, ha='center', va='center')
cbar.ax.get_xaxis().labelpad = 5
```

Plot:
[image]

Comment: Hi Aaron, instead of relying on the `ax.text` in data coordinates, maybe try doing it in relative plot coordinates.  the x axis is then from 0 to 1 and you should be able to pass `transform=cbar.ax.transAxes` to the `text()` method.  Of course, you'll need to make the x function go from 0 to 1.